# Web service process file from local file system for wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I successfully configured WSO2 ESB to process file using vfs transport from local file system.
 file://G:/test/in

Now I want to get the status of processed file via web service, such as: number of success/failure files... 
Could you please tell what web services used for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assume you cannot get this statistic, you need to do that by yourself, but for alternative, maybe you can use the status of the ws call success/failure instead in your logic, then you can get these by the monitor feature provided by the ESB.

Comment: Thanks!  Please tell me how use the status of the ws call success/failure?